# Relating functors to relational functors with the parametricity translation

Tags: type-theory, ct.category-theory, parametricity

$\newcommand{\Type}{\text{Type}}\newcommand{\id}{\text{id}}\newcommand{\map}{\text{map}}$
In attempting to answer the question: [Rigorous proof that parametric polymorphism implies naturality using parametricity?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/136359/rigorous-proof-that-parametric-polymorphism-implies-naturality-using-parametrici/136624#136624) I tried showing that one obtains the theory of *relational functors* by applying the parametricity translation to the theory of functors, where relational functors are defined in [Logical Relations and Parametricity - A Reynolds Programme for Category Theory and Programming Languages](https://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/%7Eudr/papers/logical-relations-and-parametricity.pdf).

Specifically, if we are given
\begin{align*}
F_! &: \Type\to\Type\\
F_{\map} &: (A,B:\Type)\to(A\to B)\to(F_!A\to F_!B)\\
F_{\id}&:(A:\Type)\to F_{\map}(\id(A)) = \id(F_!A)
\end{align*}

I was able to show (with generous hand-waving) that
\begin{align*}
F_!^R &: (A,B:\Type)\to \text{Rel}(A,B)\to\text{Rel}(F_!A,F_!B)\\
F_\map^R &:(A_0,A_1: \Type)\to(A^R:\text{Rel}(A_0,A_1))\to (B_0,B_1:\Type)\to(B^R:\text{Rel}(B_0,B_1))\\
&\quad\to(f_0:A_0\to B_0)\to(f_1 : A_1\to B_1)\\
&\quad\to((x_0:A_0)\to(x_1:A_1)\to A^R(x_0,x_1)\to B^R(f_0x_0,f_1x_1))\\
&\quad\to(x_0 : F_! A_0)\to(x_1 : F_! A_1)\to F_!^R(A_0,A_1,A^R,x_0,x_1) \\
&\quad\to F_!^R(B_0,B_1,B^R,F_\map (A_0,B_0,f_0,x_0),F_\map (A_1,B_1,f_1,x_1))
\end{align*}

But I am having trouble showing that $F_\id^R$ gives some form of the identity extension property, namely that
$$A:\Type\vdash F_!^R(A,A,\text{Id}(A)) = \text{Id}(F_!^RA) $$

It seems to me that the pair $(F,F^R)$ should give a relational functor in the sense of [definition 6.1](https://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/%7Eudr/papers/logical-relations-and-parametricity.pdf).

Is my intuition that this should be the case correct, and if so, is there some higher level explanation for this (perhaps some sort of Yoneda embedding?)?

Answer (score 4):

$(F, F^R)$ is not necessarily a relational functor. Define $F : \text{Set} \to \text{Set}$ to be the identity functor on sets and functions, but let ${F_!}^R$ send all relations to the trivial relation. Then ${F_{\text{map}}^R}$ trivially holds (along with ${F_{\text{id}}^R}$ and ${F_{\text{comp}}^R}$ which always hold for any $F$, because of the proof-irrelevance of equalities), but $F^R$ does not preserve identity relations.

Going back to the linked question: if a functor is defined internally in a parametric type theory, we don't really care about whether identity extension is derivable: we always get it as part of the "free theorem" package, so every internal $\text{Type} \to \text{Type}$ functor is also a relational functor externally.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be missing a couple of things. Let me answer three questions:

1. Is $F$ required to be a covariant functor, or do we expect those properties to hold for arbitrary $F : \textrm{Type}\to \textrm{Type}$?
2. Is $F_!^R$ something you expect to be able to choose arbitrarily or something you expect to be already defined?
3. Are $F_\textrm{id}^R$ and $F_\textrm{map}^R$ something you are going to define separately or something that must already follow from other definitions?

My answers to these questions are:

1. You have written $F_\textrm{map}$ that likely will not exist unless $F$ is a covariant functor. However, the relational functor $F_!^R$ exists for any type constructor $F_!$, not only for covariant functors.
2. For any given $F_!$, there is a fixed way of defining $F_!^R$. The construction of $F_!^R$ must proceed by induction on the type structure of $F_!$. The possible type structures are determined by the lambda-calculus for which you are defining these things. For example, in System F you need to show how to define $F_!^R$ for unit type, for products, for co-products, for function types, and for universally quantified types. The explicit form of $F_!^R$ is a function that transforms any given relation of type $\textrm{Rel}(A, B)$ into a relation of type $\textrm{Rel}(F_!A, F_!B)$.
3. The parametricity theorem says that any lambda-term satisfies the relational parametricity law. You can then *derive* the property that $F_!^R(\textrm{Id}(A))=\textrm{Id}(F_!A)$ for the identity relation. You can also derive the relational parametricity law of $F_\textrm{map}$ and that law will be what you are denoting by $F_\textrm{map}^R$.

Given a covariant type constructor $F_! : \textrm{Type} \to\textrm{Type}$ , the terms $F_\textrm{map}$ and $F_\textrm{id}$ cannot be chosen arbitrarily. Those terms must be derived from the type structure of $F_!$ in a fixed way, in order to satisfy the functor's laws.

There is only one freedom here, - that of choosing the type constructor $F_! : \textrm{Type} \to\textrm{Type}$. All other terms ($F_\textrm{map}$, $F_\textrm{id}$, and the relational objects $F_!^R$, $F_\textrm{map}^R$, $F_\textrm{id}^R$) follow rigidly with no possibility of making any further choices. Otherwise the required laws will not be satisfied.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Here I assume we are given $F, F_!, F_{map}, F_{id}$ (as terms). The terms $F_!^R, F_{id}^R, F_{map}^R$ are defined as the parametricity translation, as you mention, applied to the terms $F_!, F_{id}, F_{map}$.

Comment: @Couchy In my view, once you choose $F_!$, the terms $F_\textrm{map}$ and $F_\textrm{id}$ cannot be chosen arbitrarily. Those terms must be derived from the type structure of $F_!$ in a fixed way, in order to satisfy the functor's laws. There is actually only one freedom here, - that of choosing the type constructor $F_!$. Everything else follows rigidly with no possibility of making any further choices, if we want to satisfy the required laws.